# CSS Selector / XPath needed for accessing a <span>

Tags: html, css, xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm doing a scrapy project in which I try to extract data on sponsored TripAdvisor listings (https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g189541-Copenhagen_Zealand-Hotels.html).

This is how the html code looks like

```
 <div class="listing_title ui_columns is-gapless is-mobile is-multiline">
    <div class="ui_column is-narrow">
      <span class="ui_merchandising_pill sponsored_v2">Sponsored</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ui_column is-narrow title_wrap">
    <a target="_blank" href="/Hotel_Review-g189541-d206753-Reviews-Scandic_Front-Copenhagen_Zealand.html" id="property_206753" class="property_title prominent " data-clicksource="HotelName" onclick="return false;" dir="ltr">      Scandic Front</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I was able to successfully retrieve elements such as the link, id, name with constructs such as `response.css(".listing_title").css("a::text").extract()`.
However, I have trouble retrieving anything from the "Sponsored" -tag attached to the accommodation listings - result is an empty list despite there being two listings with the "Sponsored"-tag on the website.

I tried `response.css(".sponsored_v2").css("::text").extract()`without any success.

What can I do ?

Comment: From your error description it appears you are using a wrong method name. Should be `extract` and not `exctract`. Always post a snippet of the code you have to make it easier for others to help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a typo, try changing `.exctract` to `.extract`, you have an extra `c`.

Comment: sorry there was indeed a typo (Updated the original question). I fixed it but my result is still that I receive an empty list.